# Reemplazar una matriz

Tags: java

necesito reemplazar una matriz 8x8 llena de "0" por una cadena ingresada por teclado, sustituyendo cada cero de la matriz por cada letra de la cadena ingresada,  (No es necesario sustituir los 64 espacios). Y despues una segunda matriz de la misma dimension que sustituya las letras de la cadena ingresada por su numero de posicion elevada al cuadrado.

Si me pudieran ayudar por favor se los agradeceria muchisimo.

```
int matriz[][] = new int [8][8];

    String arreglo [] = new String [64];
    String  aux;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int i=0;  i<arreglo.length; i++){

        System.out.print("Ingrese una cadena");
        aux= entrada.next();
        arreglo[i] = aux;

//Matriz de ceros
String respuesta = "";
    for(int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<matriz.length; j++) {
            respuesta = respuesta + "  "+ matriz[i][j];
        }
        respuesta = respuesta  + "\n";

        System.out.println(respuesta);
```

Comment: ¿y qué has hecho hasta el momento? ¿ que error tienes? ¿en qué parte específica estás atorado?

Comment: En realidad no mucho , no tengo mucha nocion sobre el manejo de cadenas

Comment: Sugiero que añadas una cadena de entrada de ejemplo y los valores que debieran quedar las distintas matrices a partir de dicha cadena. Un saludo.

Comment: El problema es que lo que lees por escaner lo guardas en un array de una sola dimension y luego necesitas meterlo en la matriz de ceros que es bidimensional. Para ahorrarte problemas te recomiendo que guardes la lectura por escaner en un array bidimensional de 8x8 y luego simplemente recorres ese array y vas copiando al array de ceros. Y para la segunda matriz obtienes la posicion multiplicando fila*columna y eso lo elevas al cuadrado y lo metes en la segunda matriz.

Comment: Algunas sugerencias: fijate el metodo `split` de String. Para desarrollar la lógica de las sustituciones hacete un string fijo de prueba con las 64 letras como si hubieran sido ingresados por teclado (despues cambias eso por la entrada real). y dividí la consigna haciendo un metodo para cada proceso de sustitución así podes pensar cada solución en forma independiente.